# Overlapping Vue components

Tags: vue.js, recursion, v-for

I've got a string like this:

```
"Hello World! It's me, Chelsea."
```

And a list of strings.

```
["Hello", "World", "Chelsea"]
```

I'd like to dynamically wrap the matching strings in Vue components. Individually, it looks like this:

```
<MyComponent :text="Hello"/> <MyComponent :text="World"/>! It's me, <MyComponent :text="Chelsea"/>.
```

The solution for this could be something like the following (thanks **Ulysse BN**):

```
<template v-for="s in string.split(/\b/)">
  <MyComponent v-if="list.includes(s)" :string="s"/>
  <span v-else>{{ s }}</span>
</template>
```

But we run into problems where we have multi-word strings in our list (e.g. "It's me") and more specifically, overlapping words. If we added to the list of strings "Hello World", here's what the ideal result looks like:

```
<MyComponent :text="Hello World"> 
  <MyComponent :text="Hello"/> 
  <MyComponent :text="World"/>!
</MyComponent>
It's me, <MyComponent :text="Chelsea"/>.
```

How can I achieve this functionality? I have a hunch it involves v-for and some kind of recursive function, but how I can't say.

Comment: I don't think that split is doing what you think

Comment: You're right. I'll make it Regex instead of a string.

Comment: Seems this needs to be thought through more. Some issues: 1) If your loop traverses the split string pieces, how will you check multi-word phrases? 2) Should "me, Chelsea" match ["me Chelsea"] (note the comma in the string but not in the list) 3) What will you display if your list is as follows: ["Hello", "World", "Chelsea", "Hello World", "World It's"]? In that case, "World" belongs to 2 separate parent phrases

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure of your use case, but maybe something like this would be suitable:

```
<template v-for="item in myContent">
    <span v-if="item.type === 'string'">{{ item.content }}</span>
    <my-component v-else-if="item.type === 'component'" :text="item.content" /> 
</template>

myContent: [
    {'content': 'hello', type: 'string'},
    {'content': 'hello world', type: 'component'},
    {'content: 'world', type: 'component'},
    {'content': 'oh hello world', type: 'string'}
]
```

You use computed to take the string and return it in this structure, breaking out any of the matched words.